# Put req working but not returning updated object with Sequelize and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is my route for updating a user using `sequelize`

```
app.put('/users/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  const { userName } = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.update(
      { userName: userName },
      { where: { id: userId } },
      { returning: true },
      { plain: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(503).json({ message: err.message });
  }
})
```

I am still not receiving the updated user. Just an array with the number 1 inside. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @hgb123 no. From what I can see I did exactly what is written there and still it is not functioning as I would expect

Comment: You need to move the `returning` and `plain` into the second argument object (siblings to `where`)